# modify passed in variable to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

i was just playing around with javascript/jquery within mvc 3 and was just curious as to whether there was a way to pass in a C# variable to javascript and then modify from within the script. Though playing around with it, i noticed that it was not possible, as the variable passed in was just the value, and not the address.

Essentially, what i wanted to do was change a bool value from false to true when a html button is clicked. I figured i could do it through javascript but ran into the aforementioned problem. Is there anyway of doing this? Better yet, i'm sure there is a way, but is my design pattern flawed?

Comment: Your C# code runs on the web server, Javascript runs on the client.  The two can communicate via HTTP using AJAX as @Ivan mentioned.

Comment: Passing a reference (memory location) wouldn't do you any good.  You can't access a location in memory for some other computer half way around the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how ASP.Net/MVC is setup... No you can't modify server side C# variables in JavaScript. JavaScript is run in browser while C# page's code run on server. All C# classes are created and destroyed for each request and JavaScript code does runs at the different time (again destroyed after each page navigation via GET/POST).

There are multiple ways to pass data to/from JavaScript and easiest is render on GET and do submit (POST) to return changed fields to server.